# how to convert rows into column and columns into rows in R

Tags: r, rows

how can I get output like this.

my example input is

```
X  Y 
2  3
4  5
7  9
0  1
```

The required output is

```
X 2
Y 3
X 4
Y 5
X 7
Y 9
X 0
Y 1
```

Comment: `stack(df)` where `df` is the name of your dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is stroed in `df` then `pivot_longer` is exactly what you are after

```
library(tidyverse)    
df %>% pivot_longer(cols=everything())
```

Comment: No problem, if you are happy with the answer then you can except it.

Comment: It has no need to load the whole `tidyverse` just for a `pivot_longer` in `tidyr`.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just use gather, but lose the original paired order:

```
df<-data.frame(x=c(2,4,7,0),y=c(3,5,9,1))

gather(df,'name  ','value')
```

Comment: Hi @glort, a note that you can use three backticks  to put your code into a code block. I've done this to your answer as an example.